# Having trouble because of pop-up and iframe in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I am trying to run some test on web page.
url:https://online-top-up.digicelgroup.com/en-SR/
The web page has pop-up which comes up when the page is loaded. I tried closing that pop-up using the close button on the pop-up but it is not working. Because of that pop-up there is an overlay of an iframe on the other contents. I want to click on a radio-button present on the page but I am getting following error.

"button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block btn-radio is not clickable at point (683.2750015258789,406.96668243408203) because another element iframe id="optimonk-campaign-112" name="optimonk-campaign-112" src="https://cdn-dynamic.optimonk.com/public/10610/creative/208/popup.html?v=15289830281477410239"> obscures it"

I understand this is because of the pop-up and iframe overlaying the content. can Anyone help? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In first phase you need to handle iframe.

```
WebElement popframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//iframe[@id='optimonk-campaign-112']);
driver.switchTo().frame(popframe);
```

This work in any case.

But in your case, you can simply use

```
driver.switchTo().frame(id_of_frame); //this work only if iframe have id
```

After you switch to iframe, perform your commands.

At the final, come back to default content

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But the problem is that I am not able to switch back to my defaultContent. If clicking of radio button gets completed before pop-up comes up it will work fine but It will cause problem otherwise. The problem is to get rid of that pop-up window.

Comment: @aakashshah After switch to your pop-up, perform click on X button or whatever you have there to cancel it. And after go to default.

Comment: Finally I got it working. The pop-up is getting closed.Thank you.

Comment: Eventually you can put a Thread.sleep() before move to iframe to be sure pop appear. Or use explicit wait which is the best way, in my opinion. https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: I thought of putting an explicit wait but i thought that It may not be the correct way as I can not predict the amount of wait that will be required. I tried using the implicit wait with expectedCondition on element being visible but that also caused error. Anyways I have it working now.Thank you for your inputs.I really appreciate it.

Comment: @aakashshah you don't need to predict it. You can load page few times and see how much time need to appear pop-up and estimate a time. An example: If pop-up appear in 5 seconds(average) you put an wait for element to be visible for 15 seconds. And even if pop-up appear in 2 seconds doesn't matter you put 15, because after 2 seconds action will be performed and go further. You put how much seconds you want to wait for that element before to throw TimeoutException. In my opinion Explicit wait is the best way to work with selenium. P.S.: I will appreciate an answer mark, if you consider it.